# Volume of 1/2 using hull of finite point set with diameter 1

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, recreational-mathematics, volume, polyhedra

It's easy to bound a volume of a half.  For example, the points $(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(3,0,0)$ can do it.  The problem is harder if no two points can be further than 1 apart. Bound a volume of 1/2 with a diameter $\le 1$ point set.

With infinite points at distance 1/2 from the origin, a volume of $\pi/6 = 0.523599...$ can be bound. But we want a finite point set. What is the minimal number of points?

(A 99 point set used to be here.  See Answers for a much better 82 point set)

Here's a picture of the hull. Each vertex is numbered. Green vertices have one or more corresponding blue faces with vertices at distance 1. Each blue face has a brown number giving the opposing green vertex. Red vertices and yellow faces lack a face/vertex pairing.

[image: 99 points]

Some may think that [Thomson problem solutions](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ThomsonProblemSolutions/) might give a better answer. The first diameter 1 Thomson solution with a volume of 1/2 is 121 points with volume .500069.

These points will *not* fit in a diameter 1 sphere, but the maximal distance between points is less than 1. Similarly, a unit equilateral triangle will not fit in a diameter 1 circle.

Is 99 points minimal for bounding a volume of 1/2 using a point set with diameter 1?  Or, to phrase it as a hypothesis:

**99 Point Hypothesis**
99 points of diameter 1 in Euclidean space.
99 points with a volume of a 1/2.
Take one off, move them around (without increasing diameter)
You can't get a volume of 1/2 any more.

Comment: I had an answer, but then deleted it after realizing that a point set with diameter $d$ might not be inscribable in a sphere of diameter $d$. Indeed, 70 of the 110 points in your example lie outside the sphere of radius $1/2$. It might be worth noting this property of your point-set in your post. After all, the option to go outside the sphere gives us options not available to Thomson problem solutions.

Comment: I saw your answer and liked the information in it a lot, even though it was for a related problem.

Comment: Ok, I adjusted my answer and revived it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**(Update)**

My current result is $82$ points:

consider this point set:

```
pts = {
{39331, -1787,  125739},
{-42020,    -78476, 96709},
{97017, -83209, 30835},
{-17033,    70737,  109597},
{-54599,    29504,  115688},
{-69547,    63866,  91701},
{-84862,    -62280, -80052},
{111630,    -49662, -51118},
{110858,    44843,  -58218},
{7570,  -94324, 91248},
{115828,    -36578, 50910},
{-103422,   33617,  73525},
{13903, 130088, -24865},
{-48488,    -30540, -119577},
{13546, 105208, 78574},
{92754, -90941, -22055},
{-87842,    -12726, -97961},
{17890, -95311, -90222},
{-32617,    127358, -17688},
{-83770,    -100939,    6478},
{-67513,    -103415,    -46172},
{-15435,    70574,  -111233},
{42948, 122369, 28253},
{82827, -31757, -98975},
{-8841, 14824,  130515},
{-31918,    -116156,    52485},
{-124638,   33189,  26548},
{46151, -58101, 108697},
{-107711,   76927,  -3256},
{8590,  -131155,    -3832},
{-2349, -45047, 123671},
{-67052,    113066, 17470},
{-49845,    -26471, 118738},
{45038, -56580, -110986},
{124167,    -45279, 903},
{60780, -115738,    12319},
{-109374,   -68092, -27125},
{-40207,    -124921,    2722},
{74952, 40665,  100449},
{88162, -58830, 78010},
{60461, 114907, -29946},
{110136,    -3355,  -73936},
{70896, 79060,  -79787},
{56554, -97875, 67358},
{72446, -84584, -71147},
{30586, 57713,  114256},
{-15936,    -120088,    -52161},
{-480,  -46761, -124154},
{-72908,    103917, -38653},
{-101424,   28721,  -80454},
{-45115,    103290, 68859},
{41881, -117921,    -41667},
{-74575,    -93889, 53049},
{108114,    53390,  54482},
{15266, -123265,    42434},
{40723, -3854,  -126221},
{90334, 94409,  22158},
{96396, 85431,  -32579},
{-63349,    75478,  -88497},
{122169,    52183,  -1811},
{108487,    5280,   74810},
{-88785,    -956,   96779},
{-7851, 14221,  -131625},
{64857, 88850,  73124},
{23713, 102177, -81511},
{129972,    1413,   -27143},
{-119337,   -14421, 52312},
{-88103,    -51438, 82718},
{-10887,    127563, 33645},
{33805, 54367,  -116181},
{-102814,   64657,  -52366},
{-126644,   25744,  -26822},
{-25275,    110536, -68979},
{-112785,   -59627, 30034},
{-129858,   -19908, 289},
{-36740,    -84005, -95750},
{78058, 29755,  -103069},
{-118373,   -22382, -53597},
{-55526,    28946,  -116699},
{-94065,    79056,  48080},
{80742, -15619, 102763},
{129505,    8123,   26059}
}
```

Then (**Mathematica** code)

```
Volume[ConvexHullMesh[pts]]
```

is $\approx 9.00744\times10^{15}$.

And **Mathematica** sketch:

```
ConvexHullMesh[pts]]
```

[image: 82 points convex hull]

Another picture.  If all vertices of a face are at distance one from another vertex, the face is colored blue.

[image: 82 point polyhedron]

Since all point coordinates are integer, then one can write it directly (with arbitrary small computational errors):

$$Diameter = \sqrt{68\;719\;348\;253} \approx 262\;143.\;754\;938;$$
$$Volume = \dfrac{54\;044\;635\;971\;533\;362}{6} \approx 9\;007\;439\;328\;588\;893.\;666\;667.$$

If multiply all coordinates by $\dfrac{1}{2^{18}}$, then we'll get:

$$Diameter = \frac{\sqrt{68\;719\;348\;253}}{262\;144}  \approx 0.999\;999\;065;$$
$$Volume = \dfrac{54\;044\;635\;971\;533\;362}{2^{54}\times 6} \approx 0.\;500\;013\;326.$$

---

**Note**: when add any point (with real coordinates) rather close to (the center of) any face, one will get the set of $83, 84, ...$ points with described property.

Comment: I hope that my computations are without errors, but it would be great to test this result more accurately.

Comment: Amazing, that impressively beats my 96 point solution.  How did you find this, and how long did it take you?  I did check your point set, and it works.

Comment: @Ed, I use C++ for search, and Mathematica for check. (I still don't know which Mathematica function calculates diameter of point set). In a few words: first, I "sieve" points with real coordinates randomly into layer $L = \{(x,y,z): r_1 \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \le r_2\}$, and then move them slightly. And recalculate convex hull each iteration. Say, $r_1 = 0.495$, $r_2 = 0.5$; then calculate $D_0$ $-$ diameter, $V_0$ $-$ volume, and then focus on the value $\dfrac{V_0}{D_0^3}$. It takes a few hours, if memorize current not bad solutions.

Comment: If you've got best point sets for other values of $n$ handy, I'd love to see them.  edpegg @ gmail

Answer (score 4):

The current best known volume bound by 97 points is .4999609.

Currently, **98** points is the lower bound, with a current best volume of .5001309. Here's a simplified version of 98 points bounding a volume of 1/2.

```
pts = 
({{25161,15239,15738}, {-19559,26175,-6775}, {-4006,24157,-22572},   
{26243,20473,1977}, {3626,21357,25058}, {-16176,-20481,19867},   
{19600,24155,-12113}, {-20547,-23666,-10570}, {15495,-4185,28992},   
{-30124,-3246,14209}, {20518,-25644,-4873}, {-27314,-16747,8407},   
{24128,-1894,-22531}, {28918,-5278,15688}, {-9651,-30430,-8794},   
{32124,-8719,2667}, {7,-28881,15714}, {-27983,17284,5117},   
{31307,-5904,-8466}, {-29112,-13355,-7321}, {-11197,31241,2423},   
{-16493,-6895,-28142}, {-4835,-19067,26682}, {-27426,9201,16379},   
{-14201,11757,-27212}, {-13743,26726,14584}, {15279,29455,544},   
{23529,14005,-19238}, {3316,13250,-29746}, {32829,6364,-1267},   
{-17854,20459,-18567}, {23584,2651,22825}, {-31684,1388,-8352},   
{-27907,13905,-10730}, {-20649,-25299,3031}, {-7914,13803,28914},   
{-5685,31345,-9492}, {8966,26190,-18664}, {13899,26052,14660},   
{-19436,-5349,26308}, {12582,-26252,15883}, {9,3354,32858},   
{15269,12403,25837}, {-27834,-4988,-17084}, {-32368,2810,4363},   
{-18997,10095,25337}, {2653,-27021,-19141}, {14688,14913,-25846},   
{31456,5955,8605}, {22783,-19010,-14896}, {7504,-30451,-9382},   
{11921,-30012,5350}, {-6237,3312,-32379}, {5452,32220,3112},   
{4892,30443,-11704}, {20633,-13337,22304}, {13320,-19143,-23609},   
{-15014,-19141,-22978}, {1043,-33106,290}, {26794,-18693,4769},   
{-22610,4416,-23628}, {-11418,-29433,9363}, {-1517,-12798,-30638},   
{23056,-19104,13931}, {10706,-3817,-31400}, {7894,7519,30955},   
{5255,-14276,29698}, {-1278,31511,10073}, {-9977,-7220,30694},   
{-6921,22257,22989}, {29137,11121,-9805}, {-31068,-7994,1171},   
{-18843,17399,20269}, {-8660,-25176,-19425}, {12922,-18519,24195},   
{27836,-15187,-6057}, {-21640,22315,9878}, {-6851,-32147,3772},   
{-23691,-11945,18070}, {4488,2283,-32516}, {14245,5686,-28818},   
{-22214,-12745,-19863}, {22760,-11594,-20279}, {-12368,2766,29586},   
{5081,28759,15175}, {4609,-19768,-25959}, {-1159,-8679,31850},   
{13750,-25002,-14800}, {-24581,10464,-18734}, {4255,-22632,22566},   
{28756,3237,-13827}, {-9454,-14279,-28365}, {19317,-24852,6639},   
{12130,-11039,-28322}, {-6116,-4669,-31895}, {-30516,9944,-2126},   
{-24217,1636,21574}, {20094,24320,7885}} * 1/(2^20 +2))//N;

Max[EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ Subsets[pts, {2}]]  
0.999997 

Volume[ConvexHullMesh[N[pts]]]  
0.500044
```

Here's a picture of a non-simplified version of the 98 points.  All three vertices of a blue triangle are at distance 1 from a vertex on the other side.

[image: 98 points bounding a volume of 1/2]

A similar picture for 36 points, which bounds a volume of 0.4699687. I believe this is optimal.  Some believed-optimal solutions for 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, and 16 points are at my [blog article](http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/05/20/biggest-little-polyhedronnew-solutions-in-combinatorial-geometry/) and at the demo [biggest little polyhedron](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BiggestLittlePolyhedron/), which has been updated.

[image: biggest little polyhedron for 36 points.]

Answer (score 2):

A related question is to ask the volume of the largest $n$-vertex polyhedron which can be inscribed in a sphere of given size. It is important to recognize that this is a different problem, as a polyhedron of diameter $d$ is not generally inscribable in a sphere of diameter $d$. To illustrate, your 110-vertex polyhedron actually contains 70 points outside of the diameter-$1$ sphere centered at the origin (I have not verified whether some other diameter-$1$ sphere not centered at the origin might contain fewer than 70 vertices of your polyhedron in its exterior).

With that said, the question of the largest $n$-vertex polyhedron which can be inscribed in a sphere of a given size is asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979660/largest-n-vertex-polyhedron-that-fits-into-a-unit-sphere). Its solution is unknown for $n>8$, which hints that your problem might be hard to solve.

The accepted answer to that question links to a 1994 [page](http://neilsloane.com/maxvolumes/index.html) entitled "Maximal Volume Spherical Codes", which appears to use Thomson problem solutions for their putatively optimal arrangements, as they list $n=121$ as the smallest $n$ which breaches the $1/2$ threshold.

Comment: For that related problem, I get that the volume for 16 points is exactly Root[-3784084398958182400 + 1457973565222551552 #1^2 - 
   179253470562877440 #1^4 + 7618104759214080 #1^6 - 
   74727572486976 #1^8 + 847288609443 #1^10 &, 5] = 2.88645539227451858, which matches the Sloane results.  My methods match their results for 8, 9, and 16, which were among my strong results, so I would say those results are solved.  My other superstrong result is for n=36, so I'll need to check that next.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, I got down to 162 points and a volume of .5058  by starting with a triangulation of a Icosahedron and subdividing each triangle into 4 smaller triangles twice.

I improved my own first try by using a Fibonacci Sphere for n points I than calculated the volume for 100 points up to 150 poimts. At 128 points, it goes over 0.5 num = 127 volume = 0.49984077982 num = 128 volume = 0.500172211602.